# Devolver columnas si es un número de teléfono móvil

Tags: sql-server, select, condiciones, else

Necesito filtrar columnas de esta manera para que me sean devueltas solo si son un teléfono móvil (6XXXXXXXX):
Si columna Telefono1 empieza por 6 y tiene 9 dígitos, select de esas campos. Si no, si Telefono2 empieza por 6 y tiene 9 dígitos, select de esos campos.

Hay valores NULL, por ejemplo Telefono1 NULL y Telefono2 611111111, o TELEFONO1 622222222 y Telefono2 NULL, o incluso ambos NULL.

Dejo una imagen para que veáis cómo está esa parte de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando las respuestas que me han dado algunos usuario he llegado a esto:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[d_VisitasPruebas_101]
WHERE [Telefono 1] LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 1] as int)) = 9 
  OR [Telefono 1] IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[d_VisitasPruebas_101]
WHERE [Telefono 1] NOT LIKE '6%'
AND [Telefono2] LIKE '6%'
```

Pero no sé si hay alguna manera mejor de hacerlo, ni cómo hacer que solo me devuelva los móviles.

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado tenemos los [Telefono 1] que empiezan por 6 y tienen 9 dígitos

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Tabla] 
WHERE [Telefono 1] LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 1] as int)) = 9
```

Por otro, tenemos los que no cumplen esta condición

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Tabla] 
WHERE [Telefono 1] NOT LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 1] as int)) <> 9
```

Por último tenemos, los que no cumplen la condición para [Telefono 1], pero si la cumplen para [Telefono 2] que empiezan por 6 y tienen 9 dígitos. Utilizamos el operador `NOT` para negar la condición.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Tabla] 
WHERE [Telefono 1] NOT LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 1] as int)) <> 9
AND [Telefono 2] LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 2] as int)) = 9
```

Si queremos obtener una lista de los dos, podemos utilizar un `UNION` para unir las dos consultas en un único resultado. En este caso no podemos utilizar el operador `*` y debemos utilizar el nombre de los campos.

```
SELECT Campo1, Campo2, [Telefono 1], [Telefono 2] 
FROM [dbo].[Tabla] 
WHERE [Telefono 1] LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 1] as int)) = 9
UNION ALL
SELECT Campo1, Campo2, [Telefono 1], [Telefono 2] 
FROM [dbo].[Tabla] 
WHERE [Telefono 1] NOT LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 1] as int)) <> 9
AND [Telefono 2] LIKE '6%' AND len(cast([Telefono 2] as int)) = 9
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder. Parece ser que así solo me salen los que no son NULL... Cómo hago para que salgan los que tienen NULL ya sea en Telefono1 o en Telefono2? Ya lo siento por no haberlo dicho antes. EJEMPLO: Telefono1 NULL y Telefono2 611111111, o TELEFONO1 622222222 y Telefono2 NULL

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay 2 opciones, una es que quieras consolidar las columnas en una sola y otra es que quieras mostrar solo las filas con datos válidos. Afortunadamente, ambos casos los podemos poner en el mismo ejemplo.

```
SELECT *,
        --Aqui creamos el patrón para ver que telefono queremos 
        --y dejarlo en una sola columna con teléfonos válidos
        CASE WHEN [Telefono 1] LIKE '6[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                THEN [Telefono 1] 
             WHEN [Telefono 2] LIKE '6[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                THEN [Telefono 2]
             --ELSE 'Algo podría ir aquí'
            END
FROM [dbo].[Tabla] 
--Aquí ponemos ambas condiciones para solo traer teléfonos válidos en una u otra columna    
WHERE [Telefono 1] LIKE '6[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR    [Telefono 2] LIKE '6[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Si te fijas, estoy usando un patrón completo para decir que será un 6 seguido de 8 dígitos. No necesito agregar otra condición para longitud porque el patrón ya la establece.

Comment: Buenos días. No me devuelve nada. He editado la pregunta con un trozo de pantalla de ejemplo de cómo son ambas columnas.